# What tokens are in the end of line?

Tags: tex-core

Consider the following `test.tex`:

```
\ERROR
a
```

If we run `tex` on it, and start skipping tokens one by one, we get this:

```
(test.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \ERROR
          
? 1
l.2 a
     
? 1
l.2 a
     
? 1
)
```

As we see, the first `1` command skips end-of-line.
Then we see that *TeX* has just read `a` and is about to read end-of-line character. We skip it with the second `1` command.

Then we see the same picture. As if nothing happened. And only after the third `1` command we see that *TeX* has passed further.

Why *TeX* skips end-of-line after `\ERROR` from the first time, but after `a` only from the second time?

Also, it is strange that if after the final `*`, which is not shown in the output, we say `\end`, `tex` says:

```
*\end
<*> \end

?
```

instead of terminating.

**EDIT**

Consider the following 6 test files:

[control-word_at_eol.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/15fvng437qitfvl/control-word_at_eol.tex?dl=1)
[control-word_not_at_eol.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pnm7xwi6aqurm6c/control-word_not_at_eol.tex?dl=1)
[non-space_at_eol.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wwjqiwfj4tn9j51/non-space_at_eol.tex?dl=1)
[non-space_not_at_eol.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwoivwxpq7cx9xg/non-space_not_at_eol.tex?dl=1)
[space_at_eol.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wjxx6dazqi0d6i/space_at_eol.tex?dl=1)
[space_not_at_eol.tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/72097lvxnxrv65j/space_not_at_eol.tex?dl=1)

Here are results that I obtained:

`control-word_at_eol.tex`: space and ^^M is skipped right after reading control word

`control-word_not_at_eol.tex`: space is not skipped right after reading control word

`non-space_at_eol.tex`: space is skipped right after reading control symbol, ^^M not skipped

`non-space_not_at_eol.tex`: space is not skipped right after reading control symbol

`space_at_eol.tex`: space, ^^M *and* (!!!) name of control symbol are skipped right after reading control symbol

`space_not_at_eol.tex`: space is not skipped right after reading control symbol

---

Explanation of the "actually three" in the answer by egreg:

The last set of lines has three lines + two lines.
The input is

```
\def\c{\count1=}
\def\g{\global\count1=}
\def\s{\showthe\count1}
\c1\s\g2\s
```

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (preloaded format=plain 2020.9.24)
(z.tex
> 1.
<to be read again> 
                   \global 
\g ->\global 
             \count 1=
l.4 \c1\s\g
           2\s
? 1
<recently read> \global 
                        
\g ->\global 
             \count 1=
l.4 \c1\s\g
           2\s
? 1

\g ->\global \count 
                    1=
l.4 \c1\s\g
           2\s
?
```

---

Comment: correction) in file 2) space is skipped, it's ^^M which is not, in file 3) space not skipped it's ^^M. file 6) is same as 2 space skkiped but ^^M not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can understand this better with a different input

```
\ERROR xyz
a
```

If you run `tex` on it, you get

```
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=tex)
(./igor.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \ERROR
           xyz
? 1
l.1 \ERROR x
            yz
```

Error lines are divided into two parts (actually three if TeX is in the middle of expansions when it finds an error); here the top line shows how far TeX has gone in the input file, the bottom line shows what's awaiting to be read. Note that `\ERROR` sits in the top line, so it has already been read and gone. The slight misalignment between the two lines is because TeX represents control words with a trailing space, but the space “is not there” and, anyway, it is no longer relevant because it's in the top line.

With `1` you delete the next token and TeX stops again showing the context as before.

What happens with your attempt?

```
\ERROR
a
```

Let's see it step-by-step:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \ERROR

?
```

Nothing is shown in the bottom line, because the line has ended. The end-of-line has already been converted to a category code `^^M` and the generated space has been gobbled during tokenization of `\ERROR`. TeX is in state *N* (beginning of a new line).

If you type `1` followed by return, you get

```
? 1
l.2 a

?
```

TeX has entered state *M* because it has read `a` (and ignored it); the bottom line shows nothing for the same reason as before. Note that the `^^M` is still unread.

Type another `1` to get

```
? 1
l.2 a

?
```

The gobbled token is now the space generated by `^^M` and TeX enters state *N* again.

Type another `1`:

```
? 1
)
*
```

The `)` means the file has ended;  `*` means that TeX is awaiting for input. This is again in the format “top line/bottom line”: there was nothing to be ignored, but TeX follows instructions and *wants* to ignore something.

Type `\end`:

```
<*> \end

?
```

Again, “top line/bottom line”: the top line shows what has been read in so far. There is no line number, hence TeX shows `<*>` to denote something directly input in the interactive session and what it has ignored following the previous `1` instruction.

Hitting return now shows the `*` prompt: TeX is awaiting for input.

Comment: Top line does not end with a space in "xyz" example: try double click in terminal at the end of top line - highlighting will begin right after `\ERROR`, thus there is no space.

Comment: Ideally, in the original example the `^^M` converted to space should have been shown at the end of top line after second `1` command (after `a`), because the top line shows how far TeX has gone in the input file. The absence of space can be verified objectively by running `hexdump -Cv test.log`

Comment: Please fix "The top line ends with a space" sentence, as it is wrong. See answer to exercise 8.3 in TeXbook.

Comment: See **EDIT** in OP.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko It was not wrong; I reworded anyway. About the six files, I don't know what to say: I'm not going to download them from an unknown repository

Answer (score 10):

> Why TeX skips end-of-line after \ERROR from the first time, but after a only from the second time?

TeX removes any spaces from the end of the line (some older implementations erroneously removed tabs as well) and then if `\endlinechar` is in the 0-255 range that character is added to the end of the line) in plain and latex that defaults to 13 (control M).

As `^M` has catcode 5, it normally acts as space so is gobbled while tokenizing `\ERROR` and which explains the different behaviour for the first two lines.

if you delete 2 tokens then `\end` works

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \ERROR

? 1
l.2 a

? 1
l.2 a

? 
)
*\end
No pages of output.
```

using `pdftex` here.

with three 1 you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \ERROR

? 1
l.2 a

? 1
l.2 a

? 1
)
*\end
<*> \end
```

because the final 1 gobbles the next token but that is the `\end` that you are about to add....

Comment: The difference is because you do not type `1` after the last `?`.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko yes I just updated the answer